# how can i set the y rotation of an object equal to another objects y rotation without rotating it on all the rest of the axis

Tags: unity, rotation

Here is my attempt`transform.rotation = new Vector 3(0,pivot.rotation.y,0);`

I don't know what to do can you help in any way?
I have a camera that pivots around the player, but i need the player to rotate around the y axis of the pivot.

thanks in advance .

Comment: Remember, `transform.rotation` is a quaternion, not an Euler angle triplet. Did you mean to use `transform.eulerAngles`?

Comment: i forgot, thanks. il figure out how to use quaternion rotations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just modify `gameObject.transform.rotation.y` to equal the value of `pivot.rotation.y`

```
transform.rotation.y = pivot.rotation.y;
```

This is the best I can come up with. Rotations are quite confusing at times because of the [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) stuff they keep using. I don't know why they do it, they just do. It's why I stay away from everything that has a "w axis."